# Using jQuery in private commercial application

Tags: jquery, licensing

From the License
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License

Can i use jQuery for private commercial application? (meaning commercial applications that are not open source)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a dual license, pick the one that best suits your poject. MIT is very unrestrictive.

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

Answer (score 4):

The [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) states :

> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

Which means you can use a library released under an MIT License in a commercial application -- but apparently have to include the copyright notice somewhere in your application.

And, quoting the [MIT License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) entry on wikipedia :

> It is a permissive license, meaning that it permits reuse within proprietary software on the condition that the license is distributed with that software.

Comment: Regarding "Somewhere in your application", should that be visible to the end user or is it ok to just have these copy right notice at the beginning of the source code document?